# coproduct of lattices preserving filtered property of positive elements

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a complete and completely distributive lattice. An element $x\in L$ is well above $0$, denoted by $x\succ 0$, if for all $S\subseteq L$ with $\bigwedge S =0 $, there exists $s\in S$ with $x\ge s$. Say that $L$ is filtered if for all $x,y\succ 0$ the meet $x\wedge y$ satisfies $x\wedge y \succ 0$.

I'm looking for a reasonable construction that would act like the coproduct of two filtered complete and completely distributive lattices $L_1$ and $L_2$, i.e., a filtered complete and completely distributive lattice $W$ in which both $L_1$ and $L_2$ embed and such that the elements well above $0$ are closely related to the well above $0$ elements from each of $L_1$ and $L_2$. The question can be made more concrete by describing the morphisms to get a category, but at this point I don't want to commit to any particular choice of morphisms. As long as the construction is reasonable, I'm happy.

Comment: do you mean $a\succ 0$ or $x\in L$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry thanks, and corrected.

Comment: what's wrong with; if $x_1\in L_1, x_2\in L_2 \implies x_1 x_2\in W$?

Comment: What is $x_1x_2$ ? The pair ? The join ? The meet ?

Answer (score 0):

What if the co-product is simply the product ?  That way if you have a lattice $K$ and a lattice $L$, $K \coprod L$ is made of the pairs $(k,l)$ with respective join and meets. You include $k$ to $(k,0)$ and $l$ to $(0,l)$.  If you have $f:K \to X$ and $g:L\to X$, then $\theta: K \coprod L \to X: (k,l) \mapsto f(k) \vee g(l)$ is a function that make the coproduct diagram commute.
\begin{gather}
\theta ( k,0 ) = f(k) \vee g(0) = f(k) \vee 0 = f(k)\\
\theta ( 0,l ) = f(0) \vee g(l) = 0 \vee g(l) = g(l)\\
\end{gather}

If $\xi$ is another morphism $K \coprod L \to X$ such that $\xi(k,0) = f(x)$ and $\xi(0,l) = g(k)$, then
\begin{equation}
\xi(k,l) = \xi((k,0)\vee(0,l)) = \xi(k,0) \vee \xi(0,l) = f(k) \vee g(l) = \theta(k,l),
\end{equation}
so $\theta$ is unique.

You could do the same construct using the maximum and the meet instead of the minimun and the join, so I can't really see a canonical one if it were not for your notion of "well above".  In this case $0_K$ and $0_L$ are mapped to $0_{K\coprod L}=(0,0)$ and obviously the notion of "well above" translate very nicely into the product.

Comment: In this construction then both meets and joins are computed component-wise. But then $(0,y)\wedge (x,0)=(0,0)$ for all $x\in L_1$ and $y\in L_2$. So if $z\in W$ is well above $0$, then either $z\ge (x,0)$ or $z\ge (0,y)$, with $x\succ 0$ and $y\succ 0$. But these are not closed under finite meets, so $W$ is not filtered.

Comment: Um...  If you didn't manage to find the product, I don't believe you have a coproduct either then...  Everything you do is so symmetric, that your coproduct should definitively look like you product.  If I have an idea to prove that, I'll write it.

Comment: I though of this one a little more, but I couldn't find a satisfying solution.  In all insights, it seems there is simply no valid coproduct... though I did not try to prove it.  Try to contradict a properties of the forgetful (about being well-filtered) functor with colimits.

Comment: it doesn't have to be the actual categorical coproduct (which I don't think exists). Any reasonable construction that can act *like* the coproduct in the sense I describe will be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by *like* ?  What properties do you expect to be *like* a coproduct ?